# How to implement form objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, design-patterns, nested-forms

**Finally I was able to solve that issue**

I try to implement a form object pattern in Ruby on Rails 4 and I just cannot find my mistake.

I constructed a sample application for a Phonebook, which includes the following models

**Person**

- first_name
- last_name

**PhoneNumber**

- number

**Email**

- address

[edit]
Thanks to @sockmonk I could solve one problem in this code. Still it is not working...

Here is the code I use

```
# app/models/person.rb
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :phone_numbers
    has_many :emails
end

# app/controllers/people_controller.rb
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @person_form = PersonForm.new
    end

    def create
        @person_form = PersonForm.new(person_form_params)
        @person_form.save

        redirect_to person_path(@person)
    end

    def index
        @people = Person.all
    end

    def show
        @person= Person.find(params[:id])
    end

private

    def person_form_params
        params.require(:person_form).permit(:person_first_name, :person_last_name, :phone_number_number, :email_address)
    end
end

# app/forms/person_form.rb
class PersonForm
    include Virtus

    include ActiveModel::Model
#   extend ActiveModel::Naming
#   include ActiveModel::Conversion
#   include ActiveModel::Validations

    attr_reader :person
    attr_reader :phone_number
    attr_reader :email

    attribute :person_first_name, String
    attribute :person_last_name, String
    attribute :phone_number_number, Integer
    attribute :email_address, String

    def persisted?
    false
  end

    def save
        if valid?
            persist
            true
        else
            false
        end
    end

private

    def persist
        @person = Person.create(first_name: person_first_name, last_name: person_last_name)
        @phone_number = @person.phone_numbers.create(number: phone_number_number)
        @email = @person.emails.create(address: email_address)
    end
end
# app/views/people/new.html.erb
<h1>New Person</h1>

<%= form_for :person_form do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :person_first_name %> </ br>
        <%= f.text_field :person_first_name %>

    <p>
        <%= f.label :person_last_name %> </ br>
        <%= f.text_field :person_last_name %>

    <p>
        <%= f.label :phone_number_number %> </ br>
        <%= f.text_field :phone_number_number %>

    <p>
        <%= f.label :email_address %> </ br>
        <%= f.text_field :email_address %>  
<% end %>
```

(find the whole code at https://github.com/speendo/Phonebook2)

Btw. as you may have noticed, I use [Virtus](https://github.com/solnic/virtus) in this code - don't know if this is important.

If you need any additional information, please don't hesitate to let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your PersonForm class, you have these attributes:

```
attribute :person_first_name, String
attribute :person_last_name, String
```

But in your new.html.erb, you just reference :first_name and :last_name. You need to either change PersonForm to also use :first_name and :last_name, or change your template to use :person_first_name and :person_last_name.

Comment: ouch! you are right! I corrected this mistake but still the code is not working... Please appologize, but I will recycle this thread to solve the whole problem. Hope this is ok...

Answer (score 1):

The create method should redirect to @person_form.person instead.
 try

```
def create
 @person_form = PersonForm.new(person_form_params)
 @person_form.save

 redirect_to person_path(@person_form.person)
end
```